# Angular Json to class

Tags: angular

I want to create a component with dummy data and have below code for service. I want to return observable to component.

Error

```
Type 'Observable<{ "CardModel": { "theme": string; "title": string; "description": string; }[]; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<CardModel[]>'.
```

//Method

```
@Injectable()
export class PlanService {
  constructor() {}

  public getPlans(): Observable<CardModel[]> {
    return of(PlanServiceMock.plansMockData);
  }
}

export class PlanServiceMock {
  public static readonly plansMockData = {
    "CardModel": [
        {
            "theme": "",
            "title": "this is title",
            "description": "this is description"
        }
    ]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the of operator in order to return an observable from this data
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html

So inside in the PlanServiceMock class instead of

```
{
"CardModel": [
    {
        "theme": "",
        "title": "this is title",
        "description": "this is description"
    }
]
};
```

use a method to return the mock data like below

```
  returnMockData(): Observable<CardModel[]> {
       return of([
          new CardModel(),
          new CardModel(),
          new CardModel()
        ]);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to avoid creating new CardModel. I want to use json data returned by service,, which i can update in the plansMockData. So if in future i have to test my service i can just replace the value of plansMockData and see if its working correctly,

Answer (score 0):

The object that your are assigning to `plansMockData` is not compatible with your `CardModel` because the structures don't match.

Assuming your `CardModel` is something like this:

```
export class CardModel {
  theme: string
  title: string
  description: string
}
```

Now in your code,
Instead of :

```
export class PlanServiceMock {
  public static readonly plansMockData = {
    "CardModel": [
        {
            "theme": "",
            "title": "this is title",
            "description": "this is description"
        }
    ]
  };
}
```

Change your code like this:

```
export class PlanServiceMock {
  public static readonly plansMockData = [
    {
      theme: "",
      title: "this is title",
      description: "this is description"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps :)